# Questions about Git & SVN usage

Tags: git, svn

I have heard great recommendations on git & svn, so I decided to give a try out today, but I just can't seem to understand how they work, and how to use them. I understand there a difference between git & svn but I am just getting the general overview, I tried both out and I am sticking with the one I get to work.

I installed git and svn on my ubuntu machine, where I do my web development. So I installed a  git and svn main repository (remote uri) on my home folder and the working clone on my /var/www/ folder. Can I use it like this?

This is my understanding on how git and svn work, you make a main repository, then create a clone which copies the current files, then you can add/modify/delete files/folders  and then submit (push) it back to the main repository, with comments of changes (commit)...

Is my understanding of them correct? It seems to me the only benefit of using them is that you have a backup, and can give comments (commit).

Comment: Minor aside: when using git (or other decentralized tools) alone, you do not need to create a main repository and clone it into a working area. With git, every (non-bare) repository is a working area and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely agree with Thomas on docs and especially tutorials. Work through them to get actual hands on experiance.

As for your question, you have a pretty good handle on it. The important difference is that SVN is "centralized", which means that push and commit are effectively done in one step, as are pull and checkout. Git stores changesets, not revisions. Git also doesn't have a "main" repository - you can make a repository and call it the main one, but really anyone can make their own repository and push only the changesets they want.

And per mano: Git and SVN may not be meant for backup, but if you're using backup anyway, you might as well back up the repository and complete change history instead of just the current version. Then if you have a crash you still have the whole change history - but if you're doing this with SVN you do have to back up the main repo and not the working directory.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want to go with git or mercurial over subversion. If you want to get a decent understanding of how to use a distributed version control system like Git or Mercurial, I recommend you read though [HG Init](http://hginit.com/). HG Init is mercurial specific, but it's very good to get you up and running, and the concepts transfer pretty easily to Git if that's what you decide to use.

It's hard to give a full overview of a version control system in a question like this. You should read through the tutorial, start using the system, and come back and ask as you come up with more specific questions (or try google, there's lots of resources on this).

Comment: I really have to thank you for the link, it is simple, clear and really easy to understand. Again, thanks, that tutorial has saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

Just read the documentation. It IS painful, but you MUST read it. Source control documentation is simply not pleasurable. Git & svn tutorials are also worth looking at, as they'll show a more practical example.

The typical situation for using git rather than svn is if the project is very large. Subversion works just as well for smaller projects (contrary to what some say.)